# Meaning of "仕掛ける機会"

Tags: meaning, verbs

I was reading something and I came across this sentence:

> それだって**仕掛ける機会**が得られなかったというだけで、殺しそのものを失敗したわけでも証拠を残したわけでもない。

My problem is that I don’t understand what **仕掛ける機会** means in this context. I know that **機会** is something like chance or opportunity, but the verb doesn't make sense to me. Sorry if I can't ask this here.

Comment: `I don’t understand what 仕掛ける機会 means in this context.` ← Where is the context?  Had you provided enough context, you would have received a good answer a long time ago.  Right now, all anyone can do is guess.

Comment: I add it on YAMA answer, since he asked and I forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

仕掛ける means ''challenge'' or ''set traps'', but it's hard to tell which is correct from only this sentence. It's depends on what ''それ(=it)''in sentence is talking about.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that, they were talking because they failed to kill a witness and he saw them killing their target. So, the story was explaining that the killer had a lot of skills, and that they hardly ever fail to do it.

Comment: ok then that's 仕掛ける means challenge, and ''仕掛ける機会'' is ''chance to try''(to kill witness).